# Deserializing JSON to C# - Trying to turn JSON associative array into Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "AutoRefreshEnabled" : false,
    "AutoRefreshInterval" : 1,
    "AutoCycleEnabled" : false,
    "AutoCycleInterval" : 1,
    "Tabs" : {
        "RadTab_Home",
        "Dashboard"
    },
    "CommandName" : "Update Global Settings"
}
```

I'm trying to store it in this class, but I am not sure how to handle the embedded Tabs object. There may be an arbitrary number of tabs greater than 0 (so 1+, the first one's key always being RadTab_Home). Tabs shouldn't be a `string[]`. I want it to be a `Dictionary<string, string>`, but I am unsure how to express that.

```
[DataContract]
public class GlobalSettingsJSON
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = 
        LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public GlobalSettingsJSON() { }

    public GlobalSettingsJSON(string commandName, string autoRefreshEnabled, 
        string autoRefreshInterval, string autoCycleEnabled, 
        string autoCycleInterval, Dictionary<string, string> tabs)
    {
        Logger.InfoFormat("Command Name: {0}, DockID: {1}, " +
            "AutoRefreshEnabled: {2}, AutoRefreshInterval: {3}, " +
            "AutoCycleEnabled: {4}, AutoCycleInterval: {5}",
            commandName, autoRefreshEnabled, autoRefreshInterval, 
            autoCycleEnabled, autoCycleInterval);

        CommandName = commandName;
        AutoRefreshEnabled = autoRefreshEnabled;
        AutoRefreshInterval = autoRefreshInterval;
        AutoCycleEnabled = autoCycleEnabled;
        AutoCycleInterval = autoCycleInterval;
        Tabs = tabs;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "CommandName")]
    public string CommandName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AutoRefreshEnabled")]
    public string AutoRefreshEnabled { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AutoRefreshInterval")]
    public string AutoRefreshInterval { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AutoCycleEnabled")]
    public string AutoCycleEnabled { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AutoCycleInterval")]
    public string AutoCycleInterval { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Tabs")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Tabs { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Tabs does not return any data now, but no error is thrown.
EDIT: DataContractJsonSerializer does not support deserializing to a dictionary. JSON.net, however, does!
EDIT: Code worked perfectly using Newtonsoft's JSON deserializer.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx has an example at the bottom where they use a string array. This is close.. I wonder if I can adapt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `Tabs` property to be a `Dictionary<string, string>` then your representation in JSON is incorrect.  Currently, you have:

```
"Tabs" : [
    "RadTab_Home",
    "Dashboard"
],
```

And it should be a `string[]`.  If you want a mapping (i.e. `Dictionary<string, string>`), then you need a *key* to associate with the values, and therefore, a different representation in JSON:

```
"Tabs" : [
    { "key1" : "RadTab_Home" },
    { "key2" : "Dashboard" }
],
```

With this, you can definitely create a `Dictionary<string, string>`, as you would have a key to associate with the values.  The key would be to create a class, like so:

```
// NOTE: You can use POCO DataContract serialization for this type.
[DataContract]
public class Pair
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then define your `Tabs` property like so:

```
[DataMember]
public Pair[] Tabs { get; set; }
```

Which you can easily convert to a `Dictionary<string, string>` using LINQ:

```
// Deserialized instance.
MyClass instance = ...;

// Map
IDictionary<string, string> tabsMap = instance.Tabs.
    ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

You could add it as a method on your class, but that's a design decision for you to make (I didn't add it to the class because I assume this is a [data-transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)).

Comment: I am using jQuery's $.toJSON() method to serialize an associative array. I was using the associative array for key/value look-ups. Do I need to do post-serialization modification of my JSON?

Comment: @Sean Anderson: What does the associative array look like?  What you have for value of the `Tabs` property is *not* an associative array, it's just an array.

Comment: Ohhhh man. You just made my life a lot easier. I found the problem. Indeed, it was just an array, I thought I had changed code elsewhere. Thank you!

Comment: @casperOne -- I went ahead and made the change and now I do not get any data in my dictionary, but no error, either. 

"{"AutoRefreshEnabled":false,"AutoRefreshInterval":1,"AutoCycleEnabled":false,"AutoCycleInterval":1,"Tabs":{"RadTab_Home":"Dashboard"},"CommandName":"Update Global Settings"}"

This is how my JSON looks now. The tab's square brackets changed to curly, but I do not see the square brackets wrapping curly braces. Should I?

Comment: @Sean Anderson: To make your life easier, I'd create an intermediary type that has the key and the value (both as strings) and then serialize to an array of those class types.  Then, you can map the array to a dictionary easily (one property is the key, one is the value).

Comment: @Sean Anderson: I've updated my answer to reflect my suggestion.

Comment: For anyone coming here using NewtonSoft's **JSON.Net** (nuget **Newtonsoft.JSON**): given the correct JSON of an associative array, as casperOne shows, then make the type of `Tabs` be `Dictionary<string, string>` rather than `Pair[]`. JSON.Net will deserialize correctly, as Sean mentions in the second edit to his question: "Code worked perfectly using Newtonsoft's JSON deserializer.". No need to manually convert using LINQ.