# Deserialize JSON into Dictionary<string,Object>

Tags: c#, json

I’m really new to C# and JSON. I have a JSON with following structure:

```
{"person1":[{"name":"Bobby"},{"age":25},{"height":178},{"hobby":"piano"}],"person2":[{"name":"Tyler"},{"age":29},{"height":185}, ,{"hobby":"basketball"}],"person3":[{"name":"Mike"},{"age":30},{"height":192},{"hobby":"football"}]}
```

We can see as it is not a pure Object/List file JSON structure because the following parameters after the person[number] is a list. I tried a lot of methods but i still cannot manipulate those data (my understanding of JSON is not deep enough. Can you show me how access those data by using Dictionary/Database or whatever method that is easiest to do.

I have read the JSON file into a string using:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(url))
```

In case my JSON file is located at: url = @MyJSONPath

After this one I don’t know what to do anymore, this structure is weird for me.

**At the moment my current progress is:**

Thank you very much for your reply. But i tried using [Data Contract] but the program does not accept your code when i copied to my CS. (I am using Visual Studio 2013)
Anyway, i did find out a website called Json2Csharp. So it helped me generate my code to:

```
public class Person1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? age { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
    public string hobby { get; set; }
}

public class Person2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? age { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
    public string hobby { get; set; }
}

public class Person3
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? age { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }
    public string hobby { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Person1> person1 { get; set; }
    public List<Person2> person2 { get; set; }
    public List<Person3> person3 { get; set; }
}
```

Can you tell me the difference of these 2 ways of declaration. After that, how can i get the attribute of the objects.
example: i want list all the "name" into a listbox and manipulate their values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON to C# - Trying to turn JSON associative array into Dictionary<string, string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217916/deserializing-json-to-c-sharp-trying-to-turn-json-associative-array-into-dicti)

Comment: My problem is concerned with complex nested object. I did take a look at your mentioned problem but i cannot find a solution for mine though.

Comment: You have posted a question regarding deserialization, now you are talking about operating on deserialized object which has nothing to do with deserialization. Stack Overflow is not a place for live tutorial, if you have many separate problems, you should ask separate questions, not edit existing question with next problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first Stack use so i did get it wrong. I will post another topic. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your json object you have always person1, person2 and person3 you can use the following structure:

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "person1")]
    public Person[] Person1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "person2")]
    public Person[] Person2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="person3")]
    public Person[] Person3 { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "height")]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "hobby")]
    public string Hobby { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:
Of course you will have to add System.Runtime.Serialization reference to your project in order for this code to run. You don't have to use `[DataContract]` attributes, it simply allows you to keep C# naming convention.

I don't understand the rest of your question (after update) - when you have you object deserialized, you can simply access it's properties like any other object, so

```
deserializedObject.Person1.Select(p => p.Name)
```

will get you all names for Person1 array.

Additionaly, it's easier to analyze JSON if you format it (I used Notepad++ for that):

```
{
    "person1": [{
            "name": "Bobby"
        }, {
            "age": 25
        }, {
            "height": 178
        }, {
            "hobby": "piano"
        }
    ],
    "person2": [{
            "name": "Tyler"
        }, {
            "age": 29
        }, {
            "height": 185
        }, , {
            "hobby": "basketball"
        }
    ],
    "person3": [{
            "name": "Mike"
        }, {
            "age": 30
        }, {
            "height": 192
        }, {
            "hobby": "football"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i did update my progress. Could you check it :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, you have to add `System.Runtime.Serialization` to your project references in order for this code to run

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Hope it works!